# Changing Fast CGI to run a different version of python

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, hostmonster

i have a shared web server through Hostmonster. I am trying to install and run Django using python 2.6, however while they have 2.6 installed it is not the default python version. The default version is python 2.4.3, I have installed all the dependencies and Django, however the fcgi script still runs through python 2.4. Is there any way that i can force the fcgi script to run 2.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system which is hosted on tigertech.net (a pretty vanilla hosting service), I configured using excellent advice from

http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2008/installing-django-shared-hosting-site5/

You just need to make sure that the "she-bang" (first line in the .fcgi file) correctly identifies the version of python you want to run.

Assuming that the 2.6 install is located in /usr/bin/python26/, you would then have

```
#!/usr/bin/python26/python
```

as the first line of your fcgi file, instead of whatever you have right now. That tells the server which version of python (or whatever) you want the script to be run under.